Evaluate the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^3}{e^n \cdot n!}$

Evaluate $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^3}{e^n \cdot n!}$$

I could have solved the question if there wasn't that $e^n$ in the denominator by manipulation of the numerator and denominator of the fraction and shifting of the index.
But because of this $e^n$ I ain't got a clue about how to proceed. I also don't know any series that involves terms that occur in the expansion of the above function.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

The $e$ isn't special, you want to try evaluating $\sum \frac{n^3 x^n}{n!}$ (then substitute $x = \frac{1}{e}$). Presumably you know what $\sum \frac{x^n}{n!}$ is. Can you figure out what $\sum \frac{nx^n}{n!}$ is? What about $\sum \frac{n^2 x^n}{n!}$?

I think OP should have figured it out now.
